# How to combine two datasets in R using two 'by' arguments for the dplyr *_join() functions?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, dataset

Let's say these are my two datasets:

```r
# This is dataset "df"
df <- tibble(country = rep(c("US", "UK", "FRA", "SPA"), times = 3),
             date = rep(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01"), each = 4))

   country date
 1 FRA     2020-01-01
 2 SPA     2020-01-01
 3 UK      2020-01-01
 4 US      2020-01-01
 5 FRA     2020-02-01
 6 SPA     2020-02-01
 7 UK      2020-02-01
 8 US      2020-02-01
 9 FRA     2020-03-01
10 SPA     2020-03-01
11 UK      2020-03-01
12 US      2020-03-01

# This is dataset "dd"
dd <- tibble(country = rep(c("US", "UK", "FRA"), times = 3),
             date = rep(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01"), each = 3),
             cases = seq(1:9),
             deaths = seq(from = 2, to = 18, by = 2))

  country date       cases deaths
1 FRA     2020-01-01     1      2
2 UK      2020-01-01     2      4
3 US      2020-01-01     3      6
4 FRA     2020-02-01     4      8
5 UK      2020-02-01     5     10
6 US      2020-02-01     6     12
7 FRA     2020-03-01     7     14
8 UK      2020-03-01     8     16
9 US      2020-03-01     9     18
```

I would like to create a new dataset called `dj` which combines `df` and the cases column in `dd` by country and date. I also want NA to be printed in the cases column (in `dj`) where there is missing data (i.e. for country "SPA").

In essence, I am trying to get `dj` to have 12 rows and 3 columns (country, date, cases), with NA for cases in "SPA". Like this:

```
   country date       cases
1  FRA     2020-01-01     1
2  SPA     2020-01-01    NA
3  UK      2020-01-01     2
4  US      2020-01-01     3
5  FRA     2020-02-01     4
6  SPA     2020-02-01    NA
7  UK      2020-02-01     5
8  US      2020-02-01     6
9  FRA     2020-03-01     7
10 SPA     2020-03-01    NA
11 UK      2020-03-01     8
12 US      2020-03-01     9
```

I know you can combine two datasets using dplyr package *_join() functions, but how can I use these when I only want to merge a dataset with one particular column from another dataset **and** use more than one 'by' argument (i.e. country and date)??

I'm having difficulty in figuring this out myself since I'm new to R, so any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can use `left_join` and then `select` which fields you do or do not want.  Remember `?left_join` will indicate the "left" dataframe (`df` here) will keep all records which will maintain the `SPA` values.

You could also perform a `select` on the dataframes before the `join`, removing 'deaths' from `df`.  The important piece here is making sure you're using the correct `join` to keep all the records within `df`.

```
library(dplyr)

dj <- left_join(df, dd, by = c('date', 'country')) %>%
  select(-deaths) # OR select(country, date, cases)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   country date       cases
   <chr>   <chr>      <int>
 1 FRA     2020-01-01     3
 2 FRA     2020-02-01     6
 3 FRA     2020-03-01     9
 4 SPA     2020-01-01    NA
 5 SPA     2020-02-01    NA
 6 SPA     2020-03-01    NA
 7 UK      2020-01-01     2
 8 UK      2020-02-01     5
 9 UK      2020-03-01     8
10 US      2020-01-01     1
11 US      2020-02-01     4
12 US      2020-03-01     7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left_join()`, as follows:

```
dj <- left_join(df, dd, by = c('country', 'date')) %>%
  select(-deaths)
dj
```

Here is the output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   country date       cases
   <chr>   <chr>      <int>
 1 FRA     2020-01-01     3
 2 FRA     2020-02-01     6
 3 FRA     2020-03-01     9
 4 SPA     2020-01-01    NA
 5 SPA     2020-02-01    NA
 6 SPA     2020-03-01    NA
 7 UK      2020-01-01     2
 8 UK      2020-02-01     5
 9 UK      2020-03-01     8
10 US      2020-01-01     1
11 US      2020-02-01     4
12 US      2020-03-01     7
```